# Open sayduck in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to open sayduck application from my iOS application. I know I need to use URL Scheme register by this application. My problem is that I cant fint this URL. Do you know how I can check if this URL is definded?

Comment: Open the is iExplore and find the `info.plist` where there is a section that declares the app URL scheme.

Comment: Are you asking "What is the URL scheme defined by a third party application" or "How do I see if this third party application with a URL scheme is installed?"

Comment: @Stephen Darlington Yes, sorry for confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a URL scheme - but unless you're sure the user has the Sayduck application installed the best approach is to go via safari.  openURL:

http://in.sayduck.com/

This will either launch the app, go to the appropriate app store download page for the device or show a web page depending on the device type (desktop/ios/android etc.)

Disclosure:  I work for sayduck